# Trying to loop through a two dimentional array in python

Tags: python, list, arraylist

Im trying to run through a loop to find blocks in a two dimensional array but my _x variable is always staying at zero, what should i do? I can give more information if needed

```
_y=0
_x=0
while _x<= len(blocks_list)-1:
    while _y <= len(blocks_list[_x])-1:
        if blocks_list[_x][_y] != -1:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,white,pygame.Rect(_x*block_size,_y*block_size,block_size,block_size))
        _y+=1
    _x+=1
```

Comment: What are `blocks_list` and `block_size`?

Answer (score 1):

```
_x=0
while _x < len(blocks_list)-1:
    _y=0
    while _y < len(blocks_list[_x])-1:
        if blocks_list[_x][_y] != -1:
            // do your stuff
            print(_x, _y)
        _y+=1
    _x+=1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I now feel stupid for not realizing that.

Comment: Moving `_y=0` was correct, but I'm not sure the `_y+=1` and `_x+=1` are correctly indented now.